# How do you set the terminal tab title from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, operating-system

I'm aware that this can be done manually from the terminal using:

`echo -n -e "\033]0;My terminal tab title\007"`

I tried putting this into a `console.log` and `process.stdout.write` and fiddling with the escaping, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: `> process.stdout.write("\033]0;My terminal tab title123\007");` works perfectly for me ( iTerm2 )

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To save anyone reading this a bit of time, here is a function that will do it in strict mode:

```
function setTerminalTitle(title)
{
  process.stdout.write(
    String.fromCharCode(27) + "]0;" + title + String.fromCharCode(7)
  );
}
```

Comment: Well, this package also provides  a executable node script. So you can set the bash title in npm scripts: 


and _remove_ that single line of code. How cool is that :)

Comment: Using a template literal string: `process.stdout.write(\`${String.fromCharCode(27)}]0;${title}${String.fromCharCode(7)}\`);`

Answer (score 4):

```
let title = 'new title'
if (process.platform == 'win32') {
    process.title = title;
} else {
    process.stdout.write('\x1b]2;' + title + '\x1b\x5c');
}
```

in most cases, just assign title to process.title.
[image]

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: In this case, there's not much more to explain: the `process.stdout.write` is the exact same answer as the currently accepted one (using `\x..` instead of `String.fromCharCode`, which reads a bit nicer), with the only new information being the `process.title` use for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

There is node library for that: [`node-bash-title`](https://github.com/uwinkler/node-bash-title/)

## Usage in node

To install the library:

```
npm install node-bash-title --save
```

And within your script:

```
const setTitle = require('node-bash-title');
setTitle('  Server');
```

## Usage in NPM script

This package also provides an executable script. You can use that in your npm scripts. For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start:dev": "set-bash-title server && node server/app.js"
    "start:prod": "node server/app.js"
 },
```

So you can remove the title script from your code. Furthermore, the title is only set if you want to set a title(in development mode). In production mode you may not want to set a title as your script may not be executed in a XTerm :)

Comment: Hooray for adding another black-box dependency when you can do the same thing in one line of code.

Comment: Well.. this library gives you also a executable node script _set-bash-title_, so you can use it in your NPM scripts and **remove** that one line of code and black-box dependency from your code: ` "scripts": {  "start": "set-bash-title server && node server/app.js" },`

Comment: Love it.  think this is a good fit answer, especially since it can be done in package.json without having to memorise a couple of obscure hex codes.

Comment: @Chanoch If I forget a bunch of obscure hex codes I'll immediately know I have a problem because things won't work. Onn the other hand, coders love to think they can remember package names correctly, next thing they accidentally type a similar yet wrong name specially crafted by an attacker that forked + renamed the original project in the hopes that people would accidentally install the malicious version. And it works, often, to the point that it makes the news. Any legitimate reason to install a one-line NPM package has a counter-reason of equal legitimacy.