# Get console tab title in Node JS

Tags: node.js, bash, git-bash

I have found plenty of answers/packages for *setting* the tab title of a console window, e.g. [How do you set the terminal tab title from Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548477/how-do-you-set-the-terminal-tab-title-from-node-js)

Is there a way to *get* the title of a tab?  I want to set it when the app launches and reset it back to what it was when it exits.

```js
const getTitle = () => 'TODO'
const title = getTitle()

// set title
process.stdout.write('\x1b]0;My App Title\x07')

process.on('exit', () => process.stdout.write(`\x1b]0;${title}\x07`))
```

*If* it's possible, my guess is I would need to temporarily pipe stdout to a memory stream, `console.log` some voodoo, set `title = myStream.toString()`, then redirect stdout to the original stream.  I don't know what the voodoo would be, though.

I'm using [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) (inside Windows Terminal), and if there's no cross-platform way to do this (i.e. retrieving the title from command prompt, powershell, zsh, etc), I'm totally fine with that.  I did find [Linux how to get window title with just shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/764977/299211) which is a shell script that does this, but it relies on pstree, which is not included in Git Bash.  I suppose I could download [Windows SysInternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) and use `pslist64.exe -t` in a child process, but that seems like a lot of work for something that is either natively impossible or natively simple--i.e. far more work and headache than it is worth.

Thoughts?  Ideas?  Hacks?

Comment: Are you looking for `process.title`?

Comment: ‍♀️ Yes, apparently I am.  Submit it as an answer for extra rep!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `process.title`. You can get and set the value to any string or number.